# Change the avatar ratio?

Tags: images, avatar

Is there any way to change the aspect ratio of the WordPress Avatars? Or is this hardcoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible sollutions:

- Use Css with something like `overflow: hidden;` and "cut out" what you need.
- Use the filter `apply_filters('get_avatar', $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt);` and override the output of `$avatar` completely.
- The function `get_avatar()` is pluggable. That means if you hook a plugin function early enough that already defines `get_avatar()` then this function will be used instead of the core function. See [Core (link)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1655).

Answer (score -1):

The aspect ratio is dictated by the Gravatar service and it's not customizable.

Comment: true but I think you can adjust the size via url if I'm not mistaken. Gravatar sends the suse in a url. I'm not 100% percent on this though

Comment: I am talking about _avatar_ size, not Gravatar size. I can disable gravatar and use also other sources and plugins to change the image source, but they all got the aspect ratio 1:1

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can hard-code a new crop ratio by changing line **566** of wp-content/plugins/buddypress/**bp-core/js/avatar.js** from...

```
aspectRatio: self.options.aspectRatio,
```

...to...

```
aspectRatio: 1.72817,
```

... replacing 1.72817 with the aspect ratio of your choice of course.

Note you will also have to edit the same bit in **avatar.min.js** for it to work.

As it is a hack, you will have to be careful when updating Buddypress and you may have to keep re-applying the change. So if you can do it without hacking the core files then do that!

Comment: Never ever change code in any file in core or in plugins or themes which you did not author